# How to calculate cell values in excel based on the criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to a build the logic in Excel where the value gets updated based on the Load criteria .
I have attached an example where row 4 should update once the total of the cells in row 3 is >= Load value. The logic should then take the difference i.e Total - Load and then recalculate for other cells

Any help will be really appreciated. Been trying to build this however not getting my head around .

[image]

Tried to write the formulas however not getting the desired output .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use SCAN combined with MOD in `C1`:

`=LET(load,B3,SCAN(0,C3:L3,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(a>=load,MOD(a+b,load),a+b))))`

and in `C4` use: `=(C1#>=B3)*B3`

Or in one go, without the need of `C1`:
`=LET(load,B3,(SCAN(0,C3:L3,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(a>=load,MOD(a+b,load),a+b)))>=load)*load)`

[image]

[image]

If two consecutive pays can be greater than the load, as in your later added example, this complicates things and we should have a different approach:

```
=LET(load, B2,
      pay, C2:L2,
    first, TAKE(pay,,1),
REDUCE( IF(first>=load,load,0), SEQUENCE(,COUNTA(pay)-1,2),
LAMBDA( a,                      b,
   LET( c, SUM(INDEX(pay,,SEQUENCE(,b-1))-a),
        d, c + INDEX(pay,,b),
HSTACK( a, IF(d>=load,load,0))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I added another option, since it was unclear to me if you required the formula in C1 as well.

Comment: Hey PB I have attached a screenshot above (under yours) and looks like the formula isn't working as it should be. e.g. would expect 15000 in cell D3 however the output is showing 0. Also, I keep getting Spill errors when I use it for a wider horizon e.g. 52 weeks. Is there any alternative suggestion which can be used? Thank you

Comment: That complicated things, but see updated reply for my workaround.

Comment: Updated the consecutive pays greather than load version, since the logic was off in the previous version.

Comment: Hello PB , I have tried the above logic and unfortunately, it keeps giving me SPILL! error.

Comment: Spill error means that a cell to the right of the formula to where the result needs to spill contains a value. Clear the cells to the right of the formula.

Comment: Many Thanks for the swift response, That works !!! Really appreciate your help. Just lastly, let's say if I need the number updated in multiples of load value e.g. Load = 15000, Cell Value 35000 then the output should give me 30000.  Currently, it gives me 15000. Apologies its just the requirement changed recently and hence couldn't ask earlier.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPC-AK8f-3nPwLARx6-?e=dN1g0v

Comment: In that case open a new question.